# How to call a Web API built with ASP.NET Core using the Microsoft identity platform from ajax

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm developing a Asp.Net core web app and WebApi. Both are protected via AzureAD using Identity platform.
I have followed few samples posted on [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg) to implement my solution.

All is working as expected i.e. user needs to sign-in first to access web application and then can call WebApi endpoints from MVC controller without any issues.

However there is a use case which I couldn't address with my application. Instead of invoking WebApi from MVC controller, now I need to invoke those endpoints from MVC view using Ajax. However, I'm getting 401 which I guess is right because I'm not sending bearer token. My question is how can I get this token? Is there any sample for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I am really new to dotnet and I'm puzzled why you wanna use AJAX in this sample. I followed the tutorial and run the code. After my debug I found the code of getting access token(TodolistClient/Services/TodolistService.cs/PrepareAuthenticatedClient).And with the token, the server can got user information and return model to the page. The flow seems great.

And the important point is that the function of getting access token comes from SDK so it seems impossible to get the token and add it to your ajax method.

My idea is you may save the access token to another place which is suitable for you project and write a specific method to get the token so that you can use it in any place.

By the way, why not add more description of your project, perhaps someone may offer a pretty similar sample. Wish it would help.